# CSS difference between tag <a> and tag <input>

Tags: html, css, web

I am using CSS reset you can find here : https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Here is the HTML code :

```
<input class="submitForm" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
<a class="cancelForm" href="{{ path('my_path') }}">Cancel</a>
```

Here is the CSS code :

```
.submitForm {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Aero Matics", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #65BCF1;
    border: 0px none;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cancelForm {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Aero Matics", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ff9667;
    border: 0px none;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
}
```

Here is the issue :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKfjd.jpg

On the image, you can see a blank line under the Cancel button.

My question is : Which CSS property should I use to make my "tag < a > based button" the exact same size than Confirm button ? (I wan buttons start from same height and fullfill to bottom of the page without blank line).

Comment: [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `line-height` property here specially when we not adding `height` property explicitly. See following snippet I added also in top the reset css code what you applied already:

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
.submitForm {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Aero Matics", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #65BCF1;
    border: 0px none;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cancelForm {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Aero Matics", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ff9667;
    border: 0px none;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
}
.submitForm,
.cancelForm {
 line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<input class="submitForm" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
<a class="cancelForm" href="{{ path('my_path') }}">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, most of your CSS is the same, so you only need to write it once.

Second: Adding `display: inline-block` allows `margin` and `padding` to work correctly.

Third, as stated by @Paulie_D `<buttons>` and `<a>` tags (links) are not the same thing. Read the article they they suggested.

```css
.submitForm,
.cancelForm {
  background-color: #65BCF1;
  border: 0px none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Aero Matics", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cancelForm {
    background-color: #ff9667;
}
```

```html
<input class="submitForm" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
<a class="cancelForm" href="{{ path('my_path') }}">Cancel</a>
```